# Visual Studio Extensions (VSIX/DLL) into one exe

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have two visual studio extensions(vsix, I also have the dll) that I would want to combine them and have them executed/setup by only executing one .exe or setup file of some sort.

**First Extension**
[image: First Extension]

**Second Extension**
[image: Second Extension]

Is it possible to have it in the same solution, using only one executable? Or would I have to manually try to combine both extension codes into either one of the projects.

E.g. (CompletionTest into VclTooltip) or vice versa, having to also make sure no classes clash, objects not overlapping and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include one VSIX extension into another going to the .vsixmanifest designer and in the **Add New Dependency** dialog box select **File on file system** for the other .vsix. See [How to: Add a Dependency to a VSIX Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997168.aspx) for more details and options.